# OpenGL shaders compile but no rendering appears in the window

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, ubuntu-20.04

Both the vertex and fragment shader seem to be compiling and the window appears and is given the clear color but I cannot get the triangle to render. I have tried to just use the glBegin(); vertex(); glEnd(); as an alternative but this also resulted in no rendered triangle.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <gfx/shader.h>
#include <gfx/vbo.h>
#include <gfx/vao.h>

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f
};

int main(void){
    if(!glfwInit()){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to init GLFW.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    GLFWwindow *win;
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    win = glfwCreateWindow(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT, "Terraria", NULL, NULL);
    if(win==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating opengl window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(1);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);
    if(!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to init glad\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(1);
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(win, frame_buffer_size_cb);

    struct Shader s = create_shader("resources/shaders/vec2.vs", "resources/shaders/vec2.fs");
    uint32_t vaoID, vboID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(vboID, 9*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(win)){
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(s.sh);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,
            3,
            GL_FLOAT,
            GL_FALSE,
            3*sizeof(GLfloat),
            (void*)0
        );
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);


        glfwSwapBuffers(win);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

**shader.h**

```
#include <gfx/gfx.h>

struct Shader{
    uint32_t sh;
    uint32_t vsh;
    uint32_t fsh;
};

struct Shader create_shader(const char *vs_path, const char *fs_path);
```

**shader.c**

```
#include <gfx/shader.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

static uint32_t _compile(int8_t id, const char *path, uint16_t type){
    uint32_t sh; //Shader handle or ID
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "rb"); //Open the shader source code file
    long sz = file_size(fp); //Get the file size
    char *shaderSource; //Create object to holder shader source code
    shaderSource = calloc(sz+1, 1);
    fread(shaderSource, 1, sz, fp); //Read the shader source code into new buffer
    fclose(fp);
    assert(strlen(shaderSource)>0);
    sh = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(sh, 1, (const GLchar **)&shaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(sh);
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(sh, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(sh, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("Unable to compile shader id %d\n", id);
    }
    free(shaderSource);
    return sh;
}

struct Shader create_shader(const char *vs_path, const char *fs_path){
    struct Shader h;
    h.vsh = _compile(1,vs_path, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    h.fsh = _compile(0,fs_path, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    h.sh = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(h.sh, h.vsh);
    glAttachShader(h.sh, h.fsh);
    glLinkProgram(h.sh);
    // check for linking errors
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetProgramiv(h.sh, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(h.sh, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("Unable to link gl program\n");
    }
    glDetachShader(h.sh, h.vsh);
    glDetachShader(h.sh, h.fsh);
    glDeleteShader(h.vsh);
    glDeleteShader(h.fsh);
    return h;
}
```

**vertex shader**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}
```

**fragment shader**

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

void main(){
    FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
```

Comment: You've got error checking for your shader compile & link, but nothing in the main loop. Add some checks for errors in the main loop. Either you're drawing black, you're drawing backwards, you're drawing behind the camera, or you're ignoring an error.

Comment: @3Dave checking errors in the main loop makes sense. Do you have any suggestions on how to run an error check on the programs in the main loop? I would imagine it is not the shader error log like in the compile and link. My apologies i am new to OpenGL.

Comment: `glGetError`. See https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetError.xml

Comment: If you put a bunch of those in your main loop, like, after every `gl*` call, you'll find the source of the error. It's a bit of binary-search debugging at that point. For invalid operation, the help pages for each `gl*` function list the error conditions.

Comment: Got a bunch of no errors on that one, put it after every call in the loop. About this drawing behind the camera, all of my z values are 0.0f, I imagine as long as the viewport is set right, it wouldn't be behind right?

Comment: 0.0f is the image plane. Try setting them to 0.1f. We never draw anything at z=0. Also, you might want to get familiar with RenderDoc. It's not super-intuitive, but it's a very powerful debugger.

Comment: As a side note, I was somehow able to get glBegin, vertex,...,glEnd to successfully render the triangle if that alludes to any possible errors. Also my laptop is quite old so the glsl that is supported is 300 es, I dont know if that would cause other issues either?

Comment: Nah - this should work fine on a 10 year old phone.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. If you look really closely in main, it seems that you are actually supposed to call glBindBuffer to the macro GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and not to the vbo handle like I thought. Fixing this caused my program to function. Also my window hints were not taking effect because I was calling them after creating the window.